# Swagger UI for flask-potion based app

Tags: python, flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-potion

Is there a way to create Swagger-API UI documentation for a flask-potion based application?
I've tried using "flasgger", but it doesn't work for routes that are written with potion-type routes.

Flask-potion has a route specified in following manner-

```
@Route.GET('/num_products')
```

But "flasgger" expects a route in following manner-

```
@app.route('/num_products', methods=['GET'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this. However, a hackish solution for the same exists-

Flasgger works for default flask routes. We can re-define the routes that were defined earlier using flask-potion, as default flask routes and make calls to the earlier flask-potion functions from the newly created functions. Note- Changing the existing routes to the new routes didn't work for me. I had to mask the old calls with new ones and call the old function from the new ones.

Note- This only works for custom routes that are written by the user and doesn't work for default routes that are generated from data model by flask potion.

Existing code-

```
class ProductResource(BaseModelResource):
    @Route.GET('/num_products')
    def product_count():
        return product.query(...)
```

Refactored Code -

```
class ProductResource(BaseModelResource):
    def product_count():
            return product.query(...)

@app.route('/num_products', methods=['GET'])
def product_count_main():
    output = product_count()
    Response(str(output), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Maybe you can send a Pull Request to Flagger, or open an issue there with your findings? so we can support flask-potion.